# C++ : how to read a char file in a fast way into a char array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++. I am reading a character file into a character array like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  char c, str[256];
  ifstream is;

  cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
  cin.get (str,256);

is.open (str); 

int32_t fileSize = 0;
if(is.is_open())
{
    is.seekg(0, ios::end ); 
    fileSize = is.tellg();
}
cout << "file size is " << fileSize << "\n";

is.close() ;

is.open (str); 

char chararray [fileSize] ;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < fileSize ; i++)
  {
    c = is.get();  
    chararray [i] = c ;
  }

for(int i = 0 ; i < fileSize ; i++)
  {
    cout << chararray [i];  
  }

  is.close();           
   getch();
  return 0;
}
```

But this code is slow for reading large char file. Now, how to read a char file in a fast way into a char array ? In Java, I usually use memory mapped buffer. Is it in C++ also. Sorry, I am new in C++.

Comment: Memory mapping of files is part of the platform (operating system), so if you can do it in Java then you can do it in C and C++ as well. How it's done differs depending on your platform though. Also, how big is a "large file"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure C++ _does_ offer memory-mapped files.

Comment: see [mmap()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)

Comment: @TomAhh Why do I feel like the OP is a windows user?

Comment: @JanDvorak Then he can read [Msdn file mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx) page. (Thank you anyway, I totally forgot that a few people uses windows)

Comment: Another point, you open this file as a _text file_, which means that the size of the file might not actually be the same as the number of characters you read from the file (newline conversion for example). If the file contains text data, consider using `std::string` or a `std::vector` of `std::string` (one per line). Otherwise open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @JanDvorak Perhaps because he's using a g++ extension in his code?  The only compiler which will compile his code is g++.

Comment: The reference to `conio.h` seemed like a bit of a smoking gun. I was under the impression that it was an old-school winapi header containing various deprecated functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use is.read(chararray, fileSize).

Answer (score 4):

How to read a char file   into a char array:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () 
{

       char buffer[256];
       long size;

       ifstream infile ("test.txt",ifstream::binary);

       // get size of file
       infile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
       size=infile.tellg();
       infile.seekg(0);

       //reset buffer to ' '
       memset(buffer,32,sizeof(buffer ));

       // read file content into buffer
       infile.read (buffer,size);

       // display buffer
        cout<<buffer<<"\n\n";

       infile.close();     


  return 0;
}
```